# Function echoing but not returning

Tags: php

I return the variable inside the function, but it does not work. When I echo it inside, it works. I experienced very different dejavu.

```php
    protected function unique_key( $field_key, $field_keys )
    {
        if ( in_array( $field_key, $field_keys ) ) {
            $number = (int) substr( $field_key, -1 );
            $field_key = str_replace( '-'.$number, '', $field_key );
            $number++;
            $field_key = (string) $field_key . '-' . $number;
            $this->unique_key( $field_key, $field_keys );
        } else {
            // working
            echo $field_key;
            // not working
            return $field_key;
        }
    }

    // not working
    echo $this->unique_key( $field_key, $field_keys );
```

Comment: Check your error log. Do you have warnings and errors enabled?

Comment: @DaiI don't get any errors. This is very strange. I tried the function outside the class again, it is the same.

Comment: When you call `$this->unique_key(` inside the function, think you also need to `return` the value here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return $this->unique_key($field_key, $field_keys);
```

I am not sure what this function should return, but you have to add a return before `$this->unique_key($field_key, $field_keys);`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved when I returned the Hello function, as follows.

```php
    protected function unique_key( $field_key, $field_keys )
    {
        if ( in_array( $field_key, $field_keys ) ) {
            $number = (int) substr( $field_key, -1 );
            $field_key = str_replace( '-'.$number, '', $field_key );
            $number++;
            $field_key = (string) $field_key . '-' . $number;
            // Return function
            return $this->unique_key( $field_key, $field_keys );
        } else {
            return $field_key;
        }
    }
```